# use of mappedBy and query in jpa

Tags: jpa, mappedby

Hi I have a relation like this in BookEO and BookAreaEO classes respectively. Now, I wanted to understand what is the purpose of mappedBy and how I can write a query like below in BookEO using JPA

```sql
select * from book b where exists (
    select book_id from book_report_area ba
    where b.book_id = ba.book_id and ba.subject_area_id=200);
```

```java
// BookEO.java
Set<BookArea> bookAreas;
@Override
@PrivateOwned
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "book", targetEntity = BookAreaEO.class, orphanRemoval = true)
public Set<BookArea> getBookAreas() {
    return bookAreas;
}

// BookAreaEO.java
Book book;
@Override
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = BookEO.class, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID", nullable = false)
public Book getBook() {
    return book;
}
```

Comment: What is the database table name of `BookAreaEO` entity? Is it `book_report_area`?

Comment: yes its book_report_area

Comment: There are ample docs for how to write JPQL on the internet. JPQL comes with subqueries, so I see nothing obviously hard in that. Post what you have tried

Comment: Is a subquery necessary here? Simple JPQL join would do i believe!

Comment: likely it isnt necessary, but until the poster at least tries something it is a pointless exercise

Comment: I know how to write basic jpql queries but in this case I'm stuck because BookEO doesn't contain BookArea. So that is y, I was not able to start in JPQL. However, I was able to write a SQL query for this
select * from book b where b.book_id in (select ba.book_id from book_area ba where ba.book_area_id=900);

Comment: If I had the BookArea object in Book then I would have done something like 

select * from book b where b.book_id in (select ba.book_id from book_area ba where ba.book_area_id=:bookAreaId)